# Sympy absolute value and arguments of complex symbols

Tags: sympy, simplification

In doing symbolic math with Sympy I encountered the following problem:

```
from sympy import *
txx, tyx, txy, tyy, tp, tn = symbols('t_xx t_yx t_xy t_yy t_p t_n', complex=True)

#define a complex symbol
tp = txx-I*tyx

Abs(tp), arg(tp)
#will just return |txx-i*tyx|, arg(txx-i*tyx)
```

However, the absolute value and argument returned is not in the form of `sqrt(txx**2+tyx**2), atan(tyx/txx)` as you would expect for complex numbers.

I also tried

```
simplify(Abs(tp).expand(complex=True))
#returns |Retxx-i*Retyx+i*Imtxx+Imtxy|, but no further simplification
```

which worked again for complex numbers but not the symbol of complex symbol defined here. Is this not implemented yet or am I not doing it right?

Answer (score 2):

If you define your symbol list with the attribute real=True, then you will get the correct expression for Abs(tp). With your sympy symbols given as complex, then Abs() does not know the real and imaginary parts of these pieces txx, tyx, etc so the output of Abs() can not give you what you expected.

Comment: Thanks! I tried and what you said is true about Abs(), although arg() is still not working. But in my case txx, txy **should be** in general complex.